# JPA EntityManager's 'find' is taking forever for subclassed entities with combined number of rows around 10 millions

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have three subclasses (entities) extending an abstract class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Parent {

    @Id
    private long id;

}

@Entity
public class FirstChild {

}

@Entity
public class SecondChild {

}

@Entity
public class ThirdChild {

}
```

I am using Hibernate as my persistence provider and MySQL as the database. Three tables are created (one for each child).

Now, I am making a simple query to find the entity by id using JPA's EntityManager `(javax.persistence.EntityManager).`

Suppose an id is 123456789.

When there are few thousand rows in total (in all three tables combined):

```
    Parent p = entityManager.find(id,Parent.class); //Runs fine taking no time
```

When there are 10 million rows in total (in all three tables combined)

```
    Parent p = entityManager.find(id,Parent.class); //It's taking forever
```

while in the same case,

```
 FirstChild first = entityManager.find(id,FirstChild.class) //Runs fine taking no time

 SecondChild second = entityManager.find(id,SecondChild.class) //Runs fine taking no time

 ThirdChild third = entityManager.find(id,ThirdChild.class) //Runs fine taking no time
```

Whats happening here? 10 million is not that big a number. And anyway, the query with exact class runs just fine. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: look at the query Hibernate is running. There is most a join, likely a union, that is probably not indexed. `EXPLAIN SELECT` it to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, it is an Union of SELECT from the three tables

Comment: Id is not autogenerated, but I define that at the application layer. But its unique across all the three tables. I am not getting why do I need indexing here when I am retrieving the entity by its id (primary key) itself?